# Have the image fill the entire rotated div while centered

Tags: html, css

Goal: to have the image fill the containing div, yet be perfectly centered.

**Codepen example**: http://codepen.io/pdnellius/pen/bcijD

**Screenshot**
[image]

#### HTML:

```
<section class="intro">
  <div class="diamond_wrapper">
     <img class="img_hero" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="my image">
  </div>
</section>
```

#### CSS:

```
body, html {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: tomato;
}
.intro {
    background: tomato;
    height: 60em;
}
.diamond_wrapper {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: green;
    height: 30em;
    width: 30em;
    margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}
.img_hero {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to lie and tell you that this is in the center.... I had to manually adjust it to get it to what looked like the center to me. I'm sure there is a way but I don't know how to do it.... anyway the distance between two corners of a square with distance 30 is calculated using Pythagoras,

`a^2 + b^2 = c^2` Where `C` is the hypotenuse and `A` and `B` are the other sides.

`30^2 * 30^2 = sqrRt(ans) = 42.43`

So I made the width + height equal to that and then manually adjusted the image myself.

http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/Lfhbi

Comment: I think this can be the right approach if using Javascript is a possiblity. I don't think there is (yet) a way to achieve this using pure CSS.

Comment: Going to go with Leth0_'s answer for the mathematical explanation, though you and @Bonatoc both came to the same conclusion more or less (see Bonatoc's codepen). Good work.

Comment: Fair enough, Leth0_'s answer is visually more accurate. Still, I suspect JS would be a requirement if the initial size of the "canvas" div is unknown.

Comment: One final thought. If the final application is HTML5 compliant, maybe SVG masking is something worth considering : http://collidercreative.com/how-to-create-css-image-masks-for-the-web-with-svgs/

Comment: @Bonatoc masking could be fun - could make the CSS more semantic and would certainly make animation easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Tough one. This could be a start :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Aucvs

```
.img_hero {
margin: 0 auto;
height:auto;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
z-index: 0;
position:absolute;
width: 200%;
top:-50%;
left:-50%;
}
```